# Redirecting to a page in a domain using greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, greasemonkey

Basically i want to access site http://www.domain.com

what i want to do is that upon logging in, it should directly take me to

http://www.domain.com/access.aspx

But I have very little knowledge of java script, so far i made it but its continuely redirecting in in a loop like

http://www.domain.com/access.aspx/access.aspx/access.aspx/access.aspx/access.aspx/access.aspx

Why is it redirecting again and again, i just want it to redirect it once.

This is my existing code

```
var loc = window.location.href; var a = loc +"access.aspx"; window.open(a);
```

I am using a separate script for logging in, and separate for redirecting.

Comment: How are you redirecting - please post the code you already have. And please explain what you mean by 'logging in' - is your GM script logging the user in?

Comment: var loc = window.location.href;
var a = loc +"WAN1.html";
window.open(a);

Comment: That's somewhat helpful but it doesn't tell us when this redirection happens - if it's applied blindly to the domain `http://www.domain.com` then you will see the you've described. You need to identify when to do this. You could either add an `exclude` rule to your GM script or check if the current window location is already the access page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be checking if redirection is required so I suspect that your redirection logic is being applied even when you're already on the page you want to be on. Consider one of the following:

1. Add an [`exclude` rule](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules) which will cause your script to be *not* be executed on the `access.aspx` page.

   `@exclude     http://www.domain.com/access.aspx`.
2. Check before you redirect, something like

   ```
   var loc = window.location.href; 

   if(loc != 'http://www.domain.com/access.aspx'){
       var a = loc +"access.aspx"; 
       window.open(a); 
   }
   ```

Comment: but the problem is that i want to open it in the same tab...not another window...

secondly domain can be variable(in my case).....so how to counter that

Comment: Re. opening in the same tab/window: Why does your snippet have a `window.open()` then? If you just want to redirect the page you just need to [change the `window.location` value](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php).

Comment: As for the domain, you could use a wildcard in your include/exclude rules in Greasemonkey but is there a basic patten that it follow? Is the page you want to redirect to always at `http://*/access.aspx`? More information here would be useful.

Comment: basically its 113.203.128.0/ACCESS.aspx - 113.203.129.255/ACCESS.aspx

Comment: In that case I believe `http://*/access.aspx` should be what you need to add an exclude rule for.

Comment: and what should i change in the if statement

Comment: well thnx for the support..in the end i did it myself